# Drupal make block as a big link

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i'm a completely new in Drupal. I'm building a website that in the home page has the typical 3 blocks on the button where you can click and go to some specific page or article.

I create that as Block and I even create that with [Nodeblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeblock), they are displayed in the right place and with the right text and images but what I can't make it work is make them be a big link, linked to their article or page, so when user will click it will be directly redirected to the main page.

Something like:
Block: discover

```
<div><a href="lastoffer.html">Discover more about our last offer </a></div>
```

How can I do that? 
I can't find anything close on the web...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your site it's hard to say what the best course of action is, however I would suggest using the [Views Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

You could create a block with views and output any field as a link. In the Views UI you can set the url to link to any piece of content **above** it, using a token value. If you want to link to an item that is not visible, you can hide that field by selecting the "exclude from display" option in that field's settings.

You can also always use css to expand the size of the anchor tag to encompass the entire div.

Here is a tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3L9JLZOb_LQ

Comment: mhmm maybe is really what i need. Anyway that tutorial series is very good, thanks for the tips. But maybe there is already a modules or something that allow you to display a kind of "extract of a page" on your homepage, like we do with the recent comment block... do you know of something similar?

Comment: I'm trying to test your solution but all my Drupal site it become very slow and modules disappear. If you have any suggestion here is my new quetsion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064180/drupal-slow-and-modules-dont-work :(

Comment: Hard to say without more information about your setup. If your not comfortable posting your URL here feel free to message me on twitter @ryeskelton

Comment: thank you!! You are very nice :) I have no problem to post the url since the website is basically empty, just drupal and the theme: www.loungesquatt.com/drupal but can you already understand something just from that? Don't you need to see the admin interface to do so?

Comment: ah! I got it, i think. It maybe was the sitemap module that for some reason broke all the others. I took off that one and now it seems to go. Is still bit too slow but not like before.

Comment: Cool. Glad you figured it out. Please upvote my answer as I am new here and would love to gain some points! Also checkout this module for better performance: https://www.drupal.org/project/boost

Comment: I finally make it work and your suggestion is, i think, the closest solution to what i want. Now i need to play with css to make the links bigger. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

in your block add

```
<a href="your_path" class="block-link" style="display:none"></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.block-link').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).parents('.block').slice('0,1').wrap('<a   href="'+jQuery(this).attr('href')+'"></a>');
  });  
});
</script>
```