# Drupal: slow and modules don't work

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I try to work with Durpal as first time, I'm installing all the basic recommended modules but now the site is very slow (very very in particular in the admin panel) and lot of models are not enabled even if I enable them.

For example I installed the Admin menu and if I open a new window I can see it but whenever I do some operation (go in blocks or go in configuration for examples) the bar disappear! And won't come back till i open a new window.
I enable View module and view UI module but I can't see views in my structure list...

Any idea why all of these is happening?

I try with Chrome and Firefox and the result is the same.

I'm on a mac

Answer (score 0):

i got it! Seems that the XML sitemap modules broke all the others modules and make the performance very slow.
Is always worth to uninstall everything and try one by one when nothing make sense anymore ;)